# AWS Deep Lens Missing Library

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-deeplens

I got an original AWS (Version 1.0) Deep Lens from a friend and I am trying to get it to work.  I am able to SSH into the device but when I try to install the newest software I get this error.

```
aws_cam@Deepcam:~$ sudo apt-get install awscam
[sudo] password for aws_cam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 awscam : Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did some research and I have no idea where to find this ocl-icd-libopencl1 package anymore or how to install it to get this thing working.  It's like it doesn't exist anymore.  I already ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ocl-icd-libopencl1` without any luck (which updates the repo lists and nothing was found, I even did `sudo apt-get upgrade` and nothing seems to work.

I have also logged into the AWS Console and tried clicking update from there and nothing happens (probably because of the error here).  I did get it successfully registered with AWS, **just useless until it upgrades to the latest version since I can't see video.**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend performing a factory reset: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deeplens/latest/dg/deeplens-device-factory-reset-preparation.html

Comment: I have not had that exact problem, but it seems like your device is in a weird state. A factory reset seems like the only surefire way to get it to a known working state. The OS and all of the software will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

What let me get v1.4.9 of awscam installed is:

Go to https://debian.pkgs.org/10/debian-main-amd64/ocl-icd-libopencl1_2.2.12-2_amd64.deb.html and download the deb file.

Note I'm logged in via ssh to the deeplens

```
   wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/ocl-icd/ocl-icd-libopencl1_2.2.12-2_amd64.deb

   sudo dpkg -i ocl-icd-libopencl1_2.2.12-2_amd64.deb

   aws_cam@Deepcam:~$ sudo apt install awscam
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   The following additional packages will be installed:
     intel-gmmlib intel-igc-core intel-igc-opencl intel-ocloc intel-opencl
   The following packages will be REMOVED:
     srb5
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
   awscam intel-gmmlib intel-igc-core intel-igc-opencl intel-ocloc intel-opencl
   0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
   Need to get 27.8 MB of archives.
   After this operation, 100 MB disk space will be freed.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```